# Secure pages with PHP/.htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, passwords

`www.example.com/index.html` on my website is a page that asks for a password, and when entered, runs through `www.example.com/login.php`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pw']) && ($_POST['pw'] == "mypassword"))
{
// Location after Logged in
header('Location: http://example.com/kareha/index.html');
}
else
{
// If not Logged in
header('Location: http://example.com/index.html');
}
?>
```

And then gets redirected to `www.example.com/kareha/`.

The problem is, anyone can just type in and directly navigate to `www.example.com/kareha/`.

Is there any way I can protect this index file (or anywhere else on the site) so anyone who isn't logged in is redirected to the main login page?

Also, would it help if it was protected through `.htaccess`? (`/kareha/index.html` is automatically updated according to a template, which has broken every time I mess around with it)

Edit: Maybe something along the lines of starting a session with `/login.php` and then having `.htaccess` in the `/kareha/` folder check for the session?

Comment: May not fix your problem, but you need to change this `header('Location : http://example.com/kareha/index.html');` to this `header('Location: http://example.com/kareha/index.html');` because the added space between `Location` and `:` will break it.

Comment: Didn't notice that, thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this instead: http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/05/php-login-logout-script.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use sessions or .htpasswd. To use sessions, change your html files to php

**here's the top of your login script**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // see if the form has been posted
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // check for the password
    if($_POST['pw'] == "mypassword") {

        // set a session
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

        // redirect to kareha/
        header('Location: http://example.com/kareha/index.php');
    }
} else {
    header('Location: http://example.com/index.html');
}

// put HTML and login form here...
```

**the very top of kareha/index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        // redirect to login page
        header('Location: http://example.com/index.html');
    }

// put rest of page here
```

you can read about sessions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Edit: I misread the original question. Revised...

Comment: Hey Tim. Same error `header('Location:http://example.com/kareha/index.php');` needs to be `header('Location: http://example.com/kareha/index.php');` the space after `Location:` is important, otherwise it won't work. You have the reverse of what the OP had. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. copy/paste/overlook :)

Comment: Thank you, this did work perfectly. Unfortunately, the Kareha program automatically creates and runs /kareha/index.html in the absence of one preexisting, so changing it to index.php (although it did technically work) didn't work for this situation.

You mentioned something about .htpasswd, I'll check that out.

Comment: i updated the answer because i misread your question. see updated. does that help? also, your server might be able to run PHP inside .html files. Check that out - it may solve this issue

Comment: also, if you use .htpasswd you won't have to use a login form anymore, as .htpasswd will automatically present one in the browser.

Comment: It is working so far in the sense that when I access /kareha/index.php, it sends me back to the http://example.com but when I enter my password, I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in/public_html/login.php on line 18

Comment: I forgot the ; after the header() in the else block. updated.

Comment: Tim, I cannot thank you enough! I've been trying to figure this out for over a month now, and you have just saved me so much more time. Everything is perfect! Thank you for all of your help, and best wishes! I really appreciate you.