# Protecting PHP Pages in Web App

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, encryption

I am not a programmer, and I have just enough coding skills to build my own simple applications.  I am writing a web app for my own use that will be hosted on the open web.  It is typical AJAX with javascript calling a PHP page to perform a function, the PHP page reads the database and send the result back to the page.  The database data is encrypted, and is decrypted by the PHP before sending the result.

My site is protected by a user management system requiring a username and password, but, if I just point my browser to the PHP page, I get whatever data the PHP is designed to return, unencrypted.

How do I prevent this from happening? Is .htaccess an option? Is client-side encryption the way to go, and should I use javascript for that?

Thanks!

-justin

Comment: Please read about SSL and https.  If people are logging in to your site with http, the password is being sent plaintext over the internet (as is the response from the server) and so there is really zero security.

Comment: Sorry but why are you encrypting the data in the database, when your publicly showing it? Also, it makes it almost impossible to do search query. The approach your after is to set request tokens, 1 to identify the logged in user and one to sign the request (hmac). Also dont use GET, use POST

Comment: I suggest you to keep the data encrypted until you get the data in your mobile application then decrypt it with javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648403/secure-pages-with-php-htaccess

Comment: Have you heard of user session. One should use session check in header. if user session is not active any page will not be loaded, and will redirect to login page